# Is it possible to download rustup components separately and provide their paths to Rustup?

Tags: rust, offline, rustup

Our enterprise proxy and firewall settings are presenting an obstacle for Rustup's network access. The standalone installation instructions for Rust [here](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone) come with `rustc`, `cargo`, `rustdoc`, the standard library, and the standard documentation. I would also like to install `rls`, `rust-analysis` and `rust-src` to allow integration with VS Code on Windows. Is it possible to download these components separately, and provide the local filepaths to Rustup?

Comment: Ouch. Even if one manages to install all the tooling, the experience without being able to download dependencies from crates.io is going to be poor. Wouldn't you rather see how to get the proxy to work with Rustup?

Comment: The proxy works fine on my machine, but (I am informed) not in the lab. I see the "Installing from source" section at https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt indicates `cargo install --path .` can work. Perhaps I can grab a release from each github repo and use that?

Comment: Or you can copy/rsync your `.cargo` and `.rustup` directories from your machine and into your lab. I don't see why it wouldn't work.